# Adding Comments in a msg format file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a bit confused because at all the sample codes that I have seen on ROS wiki, I have seen that the comments are displayed above the code:

```
#Standard metadata for higher-level flow data types
#sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID 
uint32 seq
#Frame this data is associated with
string frame_id
```

Can I place comments infront of the code like:

```
 uint32 seq        #sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID  #Standard metadata 
 string frame_id   #Frame this data is associated with
```

Also if you are fine with both, which one is considered a good programming practice

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73924/adding-comments-in-a-msg-format-file/) by [Gudjohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/5370/gudjohnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2013-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the second variant but the disadvantage of that is that TAB is not treated as space properly so I have to untabify my files before saving them otherwise rosdoc_lite (or maybe doxygen) does not handle the file properly.

---

Originally posted by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) with karma: 1339 on 2013-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gudjohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/5370/gudjohnson/) on 2013-08-20**:
I am exactly doing the same thing right now. I am untabbing all the comments in my files and adding spaces because tab is 8 characters and space is only 1 character